# Authentication for a Multi-Tenant SaaS Applications

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

We are looking for Authentication methods for a Multi-Tenant SaaS application. We have been exploring Azure B2C but have not been able to provide suitable user to organization (Tenant) management.

We are exploring options like;

- Microsoft's Azure AD B2C or an alternate service
- B2C's Multi Tenant support to provide user/data segregation by Tenant (or Organization)

Environment;

- We are using .Net Core 2 for the application and api's
- We will have native phone applications that use the api's
- Must use a common login service for all applications (Phones and Web)

What we need to do;

- Authenticate Users
- The first user for an Organization(Tenant) would;

  - create the organization
  - sent invitations to their organization's users
- Subsequent users would take the invitation link

  - create an account joined to the organization using

    - Email/Username and Password
    - or connect a Social account to the invitation
    - or other services supplied by Azure AD B2C like another Azure AD
- From the login service return a JWT Token

  - Needs to include the Organization to secure organization data
  - the JWT needs to be passed to child API's
  - Child API's will need to validate the token without external calls

Any ideas, sample applications or alternate products ideas are appreciated.

Comment: We would also be open to any open source LDAP type of solutions.

Comment: What approach did you find to work best? I'm looking towards doing something very similar.

Answer (score -1):

We did find http://identityserver.io/

A quick summary from their website;

> The Open Source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for .NET.
>
> IdentityServer is OpenID Certified and part of the .NET Foundation.

We are currently exploring this, and wanted to add this as a possible solution to the question.